# Where did the portmanteau theorem get its name?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology

Does the [portmanteau theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) relate to an actual portmanteau somehow? A portmanteau is either an [item of luggage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/portmanteau) or a [word that is a blend of two others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)  (e.g. brunch= breakfast + lunch).

More generally, where did the name for this theorem come from?

My only conjecture is that in one part of its proof (at least the proof in *Ergodic Theory on Compact Spaces* by Denker), it "blends together" the trivially equivalent statements

$$\limsup P_{n}(C) \leq P(C) \text{ for every closed } C$$
and

$$\liminf P_{n}(U) \geq P(U) \text{ for every open } U$$

in order to prove another condition follows from either (hence both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This theorem shows that a whole bunch of conditions are equivalent.  Hence, the term 'portmanteau' or large traveling trunk.  See Billingsley's book Convergence of Probability Measures.

Comment: Oh, yes! The notorious Jean-Pierre Portmanteau, *Espoir pour l'ensemble vide*, Annales de l'Université de Felletin CXLI (1915), 322-325. Now that you mention Billingsley's book, I remember...

Comment: BTW, Billingsley's book is so good you could eat it with great vanilla ice cream and chocolate sauce. It is a glorious mathematics book with few peers.  Its clarity and coherence are the work of a true intellect of the highest order.

Comment: A marvelous play on words is underway here.....

Comment: So.... did the late Prof. Billingsley give it that name himself?

Comment: I was going to write Prof Billingsley. Sadly, he died recently.